# Absolute imports: React + TypeScript + Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, tsconfig, absolute-path

## **Issue**

I have an react app built by `yarn create vite`

I wanted to use absolute imports instead of `"../../.."` in my files, but it doesn't work in my React + Vite app.
And everything works fine in IDE. It defines my imports and redirects to my files.

Here is my import in the file.

```
import HomePage from '@/pages/HomePage/HomePage.tsx';
```

But I've got an error directly at compilation time.

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "@/pages/HomePage/HomePage.tsx" from "src\routes\Routes.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

## **What I tried**

I configured my tsconfig.json and specified `"baseUrl"`, `"paths"` and `"include"` fields.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}]
}
```

vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), reactRefresh()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
    },
  },
})
```

In **WebStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Imports** I checked **Use paths relative to the project, resource or source roots**.

Meanwhile ESLint and WebStorm give no errors.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title reads more like the tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in vite.config.ts. I removed an extra '/' from the path and it's started working properly.
From:

```
alias: {
  '/@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
},
```

To:

```
alias: {
  '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
},
```